# Get active explorer in redemption

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, outlook, outlook-redemption

I can get the active explorer like this

```
Outlook.Explorer expl = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();
```

How I get the active explorer using redemption as same as above?

Kushan Randima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redemption does expose the [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object, but like all Safe* objects in Redemption, SafeExplorer is designed to be used alongside the Outlook Object Model objects to access the functionality not exposed by OOM or blocked by the security.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Redemption is a wrapper around Extended MAPI. GUI objects such as Explorer or Inspector belong to the Outlook object model only. There is no such thing in the Extended MAPI world.

You may consider Outlook as a wrapper around Extended MAPI with its own UI.